# Find out what's the DNS server in use by the system

Tags: rust, dns

I'd like my Rust program to tell me what's my current DNS server on a Linux machine. I thought about a few options:

- Do a DNS query to `example.com` and check which one responded. I think that would require some byte-by-byte parsing of DNS response.
- Run and parse `cat /etc/resolv.conf` or `nmcli` commands from within Rust program, but these are distribution-specific and Linux-configuration-specific.
- Run some crate that gathers system info, but I couldn't find one that will include DNS settings
- Or just run and parse `nslookup example.com` which seems easiest, but not so elegant.

What would be the best solution here? Maybe I'm missing some obvious solution or there is a crate already that does it?

Comment: There isn't always a single, clear answer to the question "what is the system's current configured DNS server"; for example on macOS, different network interfaces can be configured with different DNS servers. Can you give a bit more detail on your use case? It would help narrow down the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks @Coder-256, I didn't know that about macOS. I'm playing with DNS traffic using Linux's `nfqueue` and I need to know the IP address to set the queues. I can do it manually of course, but I wanted an automatic detection. Now I can realised though that with nfqueues I'm locked in Linux, so I don't need OS-agnostic solution. Edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from @kmdreko in the other answer I used [resolv_conf](https://docs.rs/resolv-conf/latest/resolv_conf/) crate that parses `/etc/resolv.conf` file. This solution assumes that a Linux machine does have and use this file, but this will fit most of my needs. Simply:

```
let contents = fs::read_to_string("/etc/resolv.conf").expect("Failed to open resolv.conf");
let config = resolv_conf::Config::parse(&contents).unwrap();
println!("{:?}", config.nameservers); // prints: [V4(192.168.1.1), V4(9.9.9.9)]
```

for an `/etc/resolv.conf` file such as the following:

```
[adam@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 9.9.9.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`read_system_conf()`](https://docs.rs/trust-dns-resolver/latest/trust_dns_resolver/system_conf/fn.read_system_conf.html) from the [trust-dns-resolver](https://crates.io/crates/trust-dns-resolver) crate:

```
use trust_dns_resolver::system_conf;

let (conf, _opts) = system_conf::read_system_conf().unwrap();
println!("{:#?}", conf.name_servers());
```

Comment: Looks like [it just reads /etc/resolv.conf file](https://docs.rs/trust-dns-resolver/latest/src/trust_dns_resolver/system_conf/unix.rs.html#29-31), so I don't need a crate for that. But thanks for this hint, I'll be doing some assumptions based on resolv.conf and it should get the job done.